# Hibernate is not releasing connections of weblogic datasource when bound to weblogic JTA

Tags: hibernate, transactions, connection-pooling, weblogic12c

In an application we are trying to bind weblogic JTA to our hibernate sessions. Our application is hosted in Weblogic 12C and we have a datasource configured in weblogic with minimum connection as 1 and maximum as 150. This is our hibernate.cfg.xml configuration. We are using hibernate 5.4.10.

```
    <property name="connection.datasource">myDataSource</property>
        <property name="jndi.class">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</property>      
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>        
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class">jta</property>
```

When we trying to process a set of operations, we are noticing that the connections are not getting released from our application even though we are calling `conn.close()` after every operation irrespective of success or failure. When we monitored the jdbc connections in weblogic console on the managed server, we found that the active connections remained 150 when the first 150 sessions were opened from hibernate.

They never got released, till the weblogic container reached a timeout (900s in our case). The below image shows the details of connection after 900s. We didn't see any leaked connections either during the entire operation.

[image]

Question:

1. Is there any other configuration that we are missing which will allow weblogic container to return the connection to the connection pool after we clean up as part of a transaction ?
2. Can we do anything more in our application in hibernate class to release the connection back to the container's connection pool.

Update: Adding code snippets

Initiating a connection

```
private Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
        // Get the datasource name to which the Entity is attached to.
        String dataSourceName = getDataSourceName();
        if(isAutoConnectionClose){
            logger.debug("AutoconnectionClose is true. Opening session");
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactory(dataSourceName);
            return sessionFactory.openSession();
        }else{
            logger.debug("AutoconnectionClose is false. Getting session");
            return HibernateSessionManager.getSession(dataSourceName);
        }
    }
```

Here we are using `AutoconnectionClose` is `true`.

Then we perform the operation

```
public Entity importEntity(Entity entity) throws CreateException, UpdateException {
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) logger.debug("Importing entity : " + entity.getClassName());
        SessionImpl session = null;
        try{
            session = (SessionImpl) getSession();

            beginTransaction(session);
            session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);
            //Save the entity values to the hibernate cache
            session.saveOrUpdate(entity);

            // Syncs the hibernate cache with the database
            session.flush();
            return entity;
        }catch (HibernateException hbe){

            throw new CreateException(hbe,"sys.entity.create", new Object[]{entity.getClassName()} ,
                    "The records could not be created.");
        } finally{
            cleanUp(session);
        }
    }
```

And then the clean up.

```
private void cleanUp(Session session){
        if(isAutoConnectionClose){
            try{
                if(session != null){
                    SessionImpl sessionImpl=(SessionImpl)session;
                    Connection conn=sessionImpl.connection();
                    conn.close();
                    session.close();
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

We have verified from the logs that the number of open and close sessions are matching i.e. we are closing all the connections that were opened.
Thanks

Comment: The "Active Connections Current count" shows how many connections are established from the pool to the database, not from your application to the pool or the database.
When your application closes a connection, the connection is released and returns to the connection pool.
The connection pool is the only one to decide to close or not physical connections established with the database. It can shrink unused connections to get down to the inital connection count.

Comment: You can open up to 150 connections, which is huge.

Comment: Apologies, for a very late reply. We found the problem and it was a combination of things. Very high connection pool count, missing commits from applications, which resulted in connections not getting released and remaining active. By reducing the max connection count and adding the commits, the connections were released and we were  able to use the optimally. Thanks @EmmanuelCollin for the suggestions.